# How i convert single array into multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

How can I convert this array into Multidimensional array to display in json?

```
[
    [
         {
         "kitchen_id":"1",
         "thali_id":"1",
         "menu_id":"1",
         "meal_category":"Choti Bhook",
         "thali_name":"Diet",
         "menu_item":"Dal Fry",
         "item_qty":"1"
         },
         {"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"1","menu_id":"1","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Diet","menu_item":"Naan","item_qty":"1"},
         {"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"1","menu_id":"1","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Diet","menu_item":"Roti","item_qty":"1"},
         {"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"2","menu_id":"2","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Maharaja Thali","menu_item":"Dal Fry","item_qty":"2"},
         {"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"2","menu_id":"2","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Maharaja Thali","menu_item":"Naan","item_qty":"2"},
         {"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"2","menu_id":"2","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Maharaja Thali","menu_item":"Roti","item_qty":"1"}
    ]
]
```

Please suggest me code to convert into multidimensional?
I want tree view for this data.
I use this code to convert into tree view.

```
$data['Kitchen Id: '.$row1['kitchen_id']]['Thali Id: '.$row1['thali_id']]['Menu Id: '.$row1['menu_id']]['Meal Category: '.$row1['meal_category']]['Thali Name: '.$row1['thali_name']]['Menu Items']=$row1['menu_item'];`
```

but output it's not proper.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a json. `print_r(json_decode($yourJSON, true));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your data in a variable using single quote and decode it to json

```
<?php     $a='[[{"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"1","menu_id":"1","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Diet","menu_item":"Dal Fry","item_qty":"1"},{"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"1","menu_id":"1","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Diet","menu_item":"Naan","item_qty":"1"},{"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"1","menu_id":"1","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Diet","menu_item":"Roti","item_qty":"1"},{"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"2","menu_id":"2","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Maharaja Thali","menu_item":"Dal Fry","item_qty":"2"},{"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"2","menu_id":"2","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Maharaja Thali","menu_item":"Naan","item_qty":"2"},{"kitchen_id":"1","thali_id":"2","menu_id":"2","meal_category":"Choti Bhook","thali_name":"Maharaja Thali","menu_item":"Roti","item_qty":"1"}]]';
    $b=json_decode($a);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($b);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$multidimen = json_decode($yourJSON, true);
print_r($multidimen);
```